# PHP: Opendir a Network Drive of a different domain

Tags: php

So I've got two servers (Webserver and NAS on the same domain (domainB)).

I've got a PHP script on the Webserver (domainB) which list a specific directory on the NAS.

When I execute the script on my webserver it works. But if I execute the script from a different domain (domainA), for example from my local machine, it doesn't work. It seems it stops at the opendir() line.

I've XAMPP installed on my machine and if I execute that script from my local webserver it also works.

The 'testfolder' is a shared folder on the NAS and read permission is granted to everyone.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Code:

```
$dir = "//NAS.domainB.test/testfolder";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow the answers of this link, hope it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101523/iis-7-php-5-3-6-permission-denied-when-accessing-network-file

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be with access restrictions of course.
Try put

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at first line of your code.

Comment: I agree: you are essentially a guest when accessing the script from the second domain. opendir will return false if there are permissions errors.

Comment: It prints out:

Warning: opendir(//NAS.domainB.test/testfolder,//NAS.domainB.test/testfolder): Access is denied. (code: 5) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\navigator\functions.php on line 19

Warning: opendir(//NAS.domainB.test/testfolder): failed to open dir: Bad file descriptor in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\navigator\functions.php on line 19

Warning: closedir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\navigator\functions.php on line 37

Comment: I've found a php bug report with apparently same problem bug #52376. Same with me IIS7.5 and PHP5.3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I probably found the source of my problem and the solution of course.

I didn't work because my IIS was using an impersonator (probably the IUSR User) and he has no permissions on my NAS.

More Info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php (see Impersonation and file system access).

Solution:
I set the folder with the script as an application on my IIS and configured to connect as a specific user with permission on the NAS.

It would probably also work if I would give the IUSR User read-permission on the NAS.